# request.getParameter() returns null when using enctype="multipart/form-data" in upload form processing in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I want to upload multiple files along with some notes using enctype="multipart/form-data". The files are uploaded but request.getParameter() returns null for the notes. What should i do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `commons-io` and `commons-fileupload` libraries by Apache.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Comment: I am using both libraries. File is being uploaded but, text are returned as null. What may be the reason? I need the text to write them into database.

Comment: Commons FileUpload will know how to handle the request when you use the enctype "multipart/form-data". See the link I provide, there's an example how to do that. It's simple