# Can't access text field value

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have this html that passes the value of `orderID` to a modal which is completely working. However, on the servlet, I can't seem to access the value of `orderID`, having the error of `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`. Here's my code:

Html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="clickThis" data-id="<%=o.getOrderID()%>" href="laboratories.html#myModal">
    <i class="fa fa-send">

    </i>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".clickThis", function () {
        var orderID = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-body #orderid").val(orderID);
    });
</script>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input name="orderid" id="orderid">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Upload File: &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/png, .txt, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword"/> <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Servlet:

```
        String orderid = request.getParameter("orderid");
        System.out.println(orderid);
        int orderID = Integer.parseInt(orderid);
        System.out.println(orderID);
```

At the first `System.out.println`, I am getting a `null`. And after that, I'm getting the error in this line: `int orderID = Integer.parseInt(orderid);`

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null. I am getting a null from request.getParameter("orderid"); and cannot convert it into an integer.

Comment: How are you calling the servlet? Check whether the correct parameters are being passed through Network tab of your browser console.

Comment: The modal is inside a <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="SubmitResult" method="POST"></form>

Comment: Can you try : <input type=hidden name="orderid" id="orderid" value=" "> and check if it is working?

Comment: Please add `console.log(orderID)` after `var orderID = $(this).data('id');` in your JS and check the output.

Comment: Can you open browse console and see what data is sent in form? Secondly what value has been rendered for data-id? Mayby you are holding a wrong id in the first place.

Comment: Arpit and Shaunak D: It is still not working..

@Beri: The value inside the data-id is an integer. I can see that it is successfully passing the value of the data-id with the code <input name="orderid" id="orderid">. However, I don't know why I can't access it in the servlet..

Comment: See my answer. If you remove the `enctype` from the `form` it will work. But if you need to upload files you cannot use `request.getParameter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrive the parameter but not in a norma way. `request.getParameter` will not work.

You have to retrive it from the multipart request stream which is some what complicate.. You can use **[Apaceh commans file upload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)** api. This will make this task much easier.

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
Iterator<FileItemStream> fileIter = upload.getItemIterator(request);

HashMap<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>()
while(fileIter.hasNext()){
  FileItemStream fileItem = fileIter.next();
  if(fileItem.isFormFIeld()){
     paramName = item.getFieldName();
     InputStream stream = item.openStream();
     paramValue =  Streams.asString(stream);
     parameters.put(paramName,paramValue )
  }else{
     InputStream instrm =  item.openStream();
     //Receive and save File
  }

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Do I still need add additional JAR files with this?

Comment: Yes Apache commons file upload library jars and its dependencies. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

Comment: Is that the commons-fileupload-1.3.1-src.zip? I still can't make it work.

Comment: no. download the binary. commons-fileupload-1.3.1-bin.zip http://apache.osuosl.org//commons/fileupload/binaries/commons-fileupload-1.3.1-bin.zip.  Unzip it, find the jras and add them to your class path.  Make sure that you have all the dependant jars.

Answer (score 1):

One reason can be that you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and in these cases the other parameters are returned as null apart from `input type="file"`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023130/1138214)

Comment: So this basically means that I cannot get the value of orderID when I have an enctype in my form?

Comment: You can but through a different methodology.